# jQuery Get code from iFrame - Only the code from the given div id

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to get the code from an iframe:

```
var data = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

This will get the whole code from the page.

There is a div with an id of mydata in the code and what I want is to only the the code from the div.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to use jQuery or not (since the title is confusing), but using jQuery, it can be done like this:

```
var data = $("#iframe_id").contents().find("#mydata");
```

This will get you the element from the iframe which has the ID `mydata`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with plain vanilla Javascript after `iframe` is loaded and only if it's under the same domain (for security reasons).

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_Id');
var iframeContent = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var iframeContentId = iframeContent.getElementById('mydata');
```